# Dynamic SQL In a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have built this script and it successfully creates the database but it does not attach it. Do you know how I can attach?
(updated based on comments changed `MYTABLE` to `MYDATABASE` and added `USE [MYDATASBASE]`)

```
    USE [master]
    GO
    /****** Object:  Database [MYDATABASE]    Script Date: 5/26/2016 9:40:02 AM     ******/
    declare @Path as nvarchar(max)
    SELECT @Path =    CONVERT(nvarchar(max),SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath'))
    Print (@Path)
    declare @sql as nvarchar(max)
    set @sql = N'CREATE DATABASE [MYDATABASE]
    ON (NAME = N''MYDATABASE'',
        FILENAME = N''' + @Path + 'MYDATABASE.mdf'', SIZE = 18432KB , MAXSIZE =     UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB)
    LOG ON (NAME = N''MYDATABASE_log'',
            FILENAME = N''' + @Path + 'MYDATABASE_1.ldf'', SIZE = 6272KB ,    MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%) ALTER DATABASE [MYDATABASE] SET    COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100'
    --PRINT (@sql)
    EXEC(@sql)
    GO
    USE [MYDATABASE]
    IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
    EXEC [MYDATABASE].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
    GO
    ALTER DATABASE [MYDATABASE] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF
    -MORE SCHEMA AND DATA BELOW HERE…
```

Comment: Did you refresh the databases list in SSMS after you run this script?

Comment: The target machine that is having SQL Express installed, will not have SSMS installed.  So, no.